# TFS does not destroy files, unused space does not get set free

Tags: sql-server, tfs, cmd, tfs-2015, tf-cli

I deleted a lot of files and used the `TF DESTROY` cmd tool afterwards.
After realizing that I missed the `/startcleanup` command I thought like "oh, well, tomorrow the space will be free since TFS cleans up by itself".

The next day: nothing happened, around 80GB should be freed up.

I went to MSSQL management studio, searched and run the stored procedures "delete unused content" and "delete unused files" and guess what happened?: I lost around 20GB of space out of nowhere, so by the time 80GB should be free, but I lost 20GB.

Any explanation of this? something I did wrong?

I am using TFS 15

Comment: When you exec the prc_DeleteUnusedFiles and prc_DeleteUnusedContent stored procedures, what values do you set to the procedure parameters?

Comment: for prc_DeleteUnusedFiles = @partitionID=1 and for prc_DeleteUnusedContent = @partitionID=1 and @chunksize=100. I spend a lot of time on google and tryed various things but just nothing works

Comment: Did you check it today, is there any decrease on your database?

Comment: Just checked, Nothing Happened, Im thinking about to update to TFS 2017, maybe it gets fixed there

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the size of the database then you may need to manually resize this to free up space.

Delete operations from a table or update operations that cause a row to move can immediately free up space on a page by removing references to the row. However, under certain circumstances, the row can physically remain on the data page as a ghost record. Ghost records are periodically removed by a background process. This residual data is not returned by the Database Engine in response to queries.

However, in environments in which the physical security of the data or backup files is at risk, you can use sp_clean_db_free_space to clean these ghost records.